# Recuperar valor de input y pasarlo a variable php

Tags: php, html

Tengo un input donde se le asigna un valor, no lo llena el usuario, sino que otro calculo, pero no puedo pasar ese valor a una variable PHP, parte de mi código es:

```
<td>
                   <span class="fa fa-star"  style="cursor:pointer;" id="1Estrella+<?php echo $row["ID"]; ?>"></span>
                   <span class="fa fa-star"  style="cursor:pointer;" id="2Estrella+<?php echo $row["ID"]; ?>"></span>
                   <span class="fa fa-star"  style="cursor:pointer;" id="3Estrella+<?php echo $row["ID"]; ?>"></span>
                   <span class="fa fa-star"  style="cursor:pointer;" id="4Estrella+<?php echo $row["ID"]; ?>"></span>
                   <span class="fa fa-star"  style="cursor:pointer;" id="5Estrella+<?php echo $row["ID"]; ?>"></span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <input type="text" class="calificacion form-control" name="totpuntaje" disabled>
                   
  </td>
```

entonces no puedo hacer para que el valor de totpuntaje poder llevarlo a PHP, he tratado con POST, pero siempre es cero, como si por el hecho de ser un valor asignado no toma el valor que tiene ese inptu.

Ojalá puedan ayudarme.

Gracias

Comment: agrega el codigo

Comment: Creo que a tu pregunta le falta algo mas de desarrollo consulta [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Para postear datos tendrías que crear un `form` y meter los datos en `input` u otros contenedores propios de `form`. Otra forma de hacerlo es pasándo los datos en la URL o mediante Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Si has confirmado que el valor que le pasaste al input es correcto entonces el error es el atributo "disabled" , este atributo hace que no se envíe el valor al hacer post ,intenta  quitando el atributo o agregando un input oculto para enviar el dato y el disabled solo para mostrarlo:

```
<input type="text" disabled  value="100">
<input type="hidden" name="totpuntaje" value="100">
```

Comment: ok Mauro, lo veré y te comento... gracias

Comment: no, en realidad  no entiendo estoy probando con: <input type="text" class="calificacion form-control" name="totpuntaje">
                        
                        <?php $totpuntaje=$_POST['totpuntaje']; echo $totpuntaje; ?>

Comment: En el input que tiene el disabled, solo pones el value para mostrarlo en la web, el atributo hidden es el que realmente enviarás por post, los valores dentro de input se ponen de la siguiente manera : <input  type='text' value="100" name="totpuntaje"> , en el atributo value va el valor que se va enviar como post, el input que copiaste no tiene un valor establecido, yo le puse valor 100.